# How can rewrite this sql to sqlalchemy?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have the following tables:

```
table_1 (
    id_1 Integer,
    ranges_1 datetimerange[]
)

table_2 (
    id_2 Integer,
    ranges_2 datetimerange[]
)
```

it is necessary, knowing the id of the row of the first table, find all the id of the second table, with which it overlaps.

The following sql code does this

```
select id_2 from table_2,
(select unnest(ranges_1) as wh from table_1 where id_1=1) as q1,
lateral unnest(table_2.range_2) as dh
group by id_2
having (wh && dh).bool_or
```

How can this be rewritten to sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

engine = create_engine('postgresql://username:pass@host:port/dbname')
query = '''
select id_2 from table_2,
    (select unnest(ranges_1) as wh from table_1 where id_1=1) as q1,
    lateral unnest(table_2.range_2) as dh
    group by id_2
    having (wh && dh).bool_or
'''
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, con=engine)
df
print (df)
```